# Do a question's tags lose 'weight' as more are added?

Tags: discussion, tags

Does Stack Exchange's search algorithm treat the following [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tags with the same weight/relevance?

**Question 1:**

Tags: [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [oop](/questions/tagged/oop)

**Question 2:**

Tags: [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)

Comment: No, please add as many tags as are applicable for a particular question. The "related questions" feature works much better that way.

Comment: But only add tags which *are in fact* related! Don't just go tag-crazy thinking it makes the system better -- **it doesn't!** (And they will be removed by someone else)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tags are weighted equally and does not diminish by 1/N based on how many tags (N) there are on the question.  So there is no "penalty" to adding tags.

At least that makes sense from a design perspective, database table perspective (the post-tag table should have no weight column), and just common sense as well.